# Get Count and Unique Values from one table

Tags: sql

I have a table that is structured as:

```
Check#   Invoice#
100      200
100      300
100      400
200      304
200      306
```

I want to get the number of invoices for each check number so the above table should return

```
Check#   Total Invoices
100       3
200       2
```

Comment: What database is it?

Comment: You mention Unique values, if check `200` had a 2nd `306` would the total go to 3 or stay at 2? Also the reason you are getting downvotes is performing a Group By (the solution to your problem) is a very basic SQL concept. You appear have made no attempt to research this problem before posting here and that behavior is discouraged on this site.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Check#], COUNT([Invoice#]) AS 'Total Invoices'
FROM <you_table_name_here>
GROUP BY [Check#]
```

If this is SQL Server here's a working Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/101d1/1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY` combined with `COUNT DISTINCT` to count each check's number of *different* invoices:

```
select check, count(distinct invoice)
from tablename
group by check
```